# PING token missed after un-successful Bulk OUT transfer

Tags: usb, tty, cat, serial-port, stty

I'm trying to send a large amount of data(~15 Mb) from Host to Device over ttyACM3. I have used "cat" command for sending the data from host.

Host side:    `cat ./pattern.bin > /dev/ttyACM3`

Device side : `cat /dev/ttyGS3 > /tmp/rx_pattern.bin`

At the device side i see few bytes are missed after complete transfer. By looking at the Ellisys logs,

1. One of the "OUT" transaction is failed(handshake is NAK) and there is no "PING" transaction for the failed transfer.
2. Whereas in success scenario whenever "OUT" transaction fails, "PING" transaction is present and data is sent again.

Why is that Host missed to send PING token for failed OUT transfer?

Comment: No one has seen this issue?